# How to put items in center of Grid Layout in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I am using `GridLayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`.

There are conditions where i need to draw 1, 2, 3 or 4 items per row. Like following.

[image]

I am able to achieve this by doing following.

```
//RecyclerView

 override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

        if(mDataList?.get(position)?.totalColumns == 5){
            return COLUMNS_5
        }
        else if(mDataList?.get(position)?.totalColumns == 4){
            return COLUMNS_4
        }

}
```

**On Fragment class**

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {

        //If there are 6 items in 1 row, then return 1

        switch(homeTabLayoutRecyclerAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){

            case COLUMNS_5:
                return 5;

            case COLUMNS_4:
                return 4;
```

The issue is, i am able to get the layout, i shared above, but i need to center all of the items. Like following:

[image]

Following is my `recyclerview` code.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvItems"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline32" />
```

Comment: Can you please share the xml code for the recycler view item